# Akka(Actor Model) , with Play being built on top of Akka itself, how are the actors used?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm fairly new to Akka, but with the tutorials available online, I have managed to understand how it works, in other words creating Actors and its children, creating a supervisor for fault tolerance, how messages go into the mailbox, in a fair sense, I understand how Akka works, but when it comes to using Akka with play, I have been stuck here since a few days now, I understand Akka works like threads, but with play controllers receiving request/responses, where does Akka go into it?
For a sample project, I have a html page sending data to the controller(via post), the controller receives it and runs a cassandra db query to extract data and displays data to a new page, this works fairly easy, but how do I implement this using Akka Actor Models, where does the Akka code go? do I take the http request inside the Actor and query it accordingly? Also do I write the Actor inside the controller itself?

Any kind of suggestions/books/sample projects/code snippets are really welcomed, I can share the code if required, sorry if my question might have seen vague, but in need of a little push, to explore the world of Akka.
Thank you in advance.

Note: 
I'm building the sample project on Play Framework using Scala.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should check the [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAkka). There is a nice example on how to use actors. So to answer your question you should preferably define the Actor as you would define any other class in its own file. You can instantiate it as stated in the play documentation or through a supervisor, and send it a message/asking your actor in your Action like so

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.ask
implicit val timeout: Timeout = 5.seconds

def sayHello(name: String) = Action.async {
  (helloActor ? SayHello(name)).mapTo[String].map { message =>
    Ok(message)
  }
}
```

With helloActor being your actor and SayHello being a message (case class).
In your case SayHello would query the database and return the data.
Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: I'm really sorry that I didn't go deep into the documentation and thank you this actually helped, just 1 more thing, why the mapTo and map? . Also for the person who down voted the answer, at least he cleared my doubt, why down vote?

Comment: Concerning the mapTo you can check here : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/futures.html. The mapTo method will return a new Future that contains the result if the cast was successful, or a ClassCastException if not. Handling Exceptions will be discussed further within this documentation.
Glad I could help ^^

Comment: Thank you, I applied the same and things are working fine now.